# How to reset model in Yii2 to add new/next record?

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I'm using Yii2 framework. And I need solution how to reset `$model` to put/create next row from inside that model.

```
    <?php

    namespace app\models;

    use Yii;

    class Queue extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

        public function stackOverflow(){
            while(true){
              $this->text = 'asd';
              $this->save();
              $this->resetForNextRecord(); // ????????
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: A model should represent *one* object of the class that implements. The way you are using `Queue` in your code is better suited to structural programming. If you want to make the most out of OOP you could consider taking the loop outside the class and creating a new `Queue` object for each element that you want to save to the database.

Comment: Yes, you have right, but this function is responsible for download data from internet then parse it and finally make complete data in database. So, in my opinion it is right way what I did

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It was more easy than I thought.

```
$model->setIsNewRecord(true);
$model->id = NULL;
```